# What does UPLOADS_DEFAULT_URL configuration value in flask uploads mean?

Tags: python, flask, flask-uploads

From [this page](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Uploads/):

> **UPLOADS_DEFAULT_URL**
>
> > If you have a server set up to serve from
> >     UPLOADS_DEFAULT_DEST, then set the server’s base URL here. Continuing
> >     the example above, if /var/uploads is accessible from
> >     http://localhost:5001, then you would set this to
> >     http://localhost:5001/ and URLs for the photos set would start with
> >     http://localhost:5001/photos. Include the trailing slash.
>
> However, you
>   don’t have to set any of the _URL settings - if you don’t, then they
>   will be served internally by Flask. They are just there so if you have
>   heavy upload traffic, you can have a faster production server like
>   Nginx or Lighttpd serve the uploads.

I do not understand how Flask uses UPLOADS_DEFAULT_URL. The text says that if you don't specify it the uploads will be served internally by flask. Questions:

1. On what url are they going to be served by flask if I don't specify the url?
2. If I do specify URL what flask is going to do with it? How is it going to use it?

So it's easier to answer my question: I don't know how exactly python interacts with a web server such as apache or nginx. I do understand that in principle you want these web servers to front/proxy you python app for scalability/load but I don't know exact details on how this is done. May be if I knew that, the information above would be more obvious to me.

From practical perspective: I have someone else's [python/flask app](https://github.com/Deimos/SolutionNet), and not a lot of experience with python. The parameter above needs to be specified in [the config files](https://github.com/Deimos/SolutionNet/blob/master/spacechem.cfg.example). I got the app up and running, I did not specify this particular parameter, the uploads are working fine. I'm wondering what else could I have possibly broken by not specifying the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On what url are they going to be served by flask if I don't specify the url?

From the doc i understand that if you set like this

```
UPLOADS_DEFAULT_DEST = '/var/uploads/'
UPLOADS_DEFAULT_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/'
```

Then when you upload a set named photos will store its uploads in `/var/uploads/photos`.Lets assume it as `/var/uploads/photos/test.jpg`.Then flask will serve the image as

```
http://localhost:5000/photos/test.jpg.
```

> If I do specify URL what flask is going to do with it? How is it going to use it?

Let if

```
UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST = '/var/mypics/'
UPLOADED_PHOTOS_URL =  'http://localhost:5000/'
```

Then when you upload a set named photos will store its uploads in `/var/mypics/`.Lets assume it as `/var/mypics/test.jpg`.Then flask will serve the image as

```
http://localhost:5000/test.jpg.
```

But we do not use this in `production`.In production images, statics should be served by `nginx` or `apache`

Comment: Sorry, I mean if the url I specified is elsewhere in the internet? Not on this application site?

Comment: `url` doesnt depend on upload part. If you specify like this, `.url` of photos instance will get `http://not-this-site.com/uploads/photos/test.jpg`.it should be 404(image is in server where flask app is running).